# How does Facebook Sharer select description when sharing my URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I am using below code on my site.When I try to share on facebook , it always pics my meta keywords content and not picking my og:descption . Is there any way I can make facebook to pic my og:description ?

```
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="Are you ready to take risks or are you more comfortable with safe rewards?  Heres how to know whether you are suited for a corporate job or start-up.">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="interview techniques,interview answers,sample interview questions,job interview,interview questions,interview tips,interview techniques,behavioral interview,phone interview,interview skills,interviews">
<meta property="og:title" content="Are you suited for a startup or a corporate job?" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://media.monsterindia.com/cmsimages/1454311052.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Job Hunt on Monster" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Are you ready to take risks or are you more comfortable with safe rewards?  Here's how to know whether you are suited for a corporate job or start-up."/>
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0):

Try removing apostrophe (') from your (Here's) word in og:description content text ... hope this helps

Comment: No its not working.I have removed all special characters

Comment: Debug your page in FB Debugger. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Put your website link in above mentioned link and see the warnings under "Warnings That Should Be Fixed".